# Is there a quick way to search the browser page for the contents of the search engine field?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser, browser-addons

When I type a phrase into the search engine field in a browser, then open one of the hit pages, I often want to search for occurrences of that same phrase on that page. This means copying the content from the search engine field, typing Ctrl-F to open the "Find in page" field, and pasting in the content. Is there any browser-native or addon functionality that makes this process more streamlined? I'd be most interested in Firefox, but Chrome would be okay, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that [SearchWP](https://addons.mozilla.org/nn-NO/firefox/addon/searchwp/) for Firefox does exactly what you need.

Comment: It does indeed!